# How to redirect to external URL in Play framework 2.0 (Java)

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

Redirecting to an internal URL seems to be possible by using the redirect() method in the controller.

```
public static Result index() {
  return redirect(routes.Application.tasks());
}
```

However I want to redirect to an external URL in the controller. redirect(String) method accepts only internal URLs as parameter.

What I require is Play framework equivalent of standard Java servlet redirect i.e.

```
request.sendRedirect(String url)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sometimes simplest solution just... works:

```
return redirect("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962694");
```

It's also worth to use [other availabe redirects](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.1/java/play/mvc/Results.html) such as

- `seeOther(String url)`
- `movedPermanently(String url)`
- `temporaryRedirect(String url)`

etc

Comment: Hey Marcus, thanks for your answer. The 3 other methods you mentioned are working fine for me. However, the simple solution, `redirect(String)` gives me this error - `Execution exception
[StackOverflowError: null]. `

Comment: @ManishKumar eeechhhh.... this is method's declaration... that means you need to insert some String there ie `String url="http://domain.tld"; return seeOther(url);` or `return seeOther("http://domain.tld");`

Comment: playframework really needs to stop adding new features, and actually documenting things