# Cannot redirect to external url

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a scala play microservice and I am trying to redirect to an external url. But I have problem because the redirect url is being appended to the domain of the service. My code is:

```
Redirect("www.google.com", 302)
```

But when I run my controller method in the browser it tries to redirect to this url

```
http://localhost:9000/www.google.com
```

and it complains telling me that there is no end point defined in the router with

```
Action Not Found

GET /www.google.com
```

How can I make it redirect to just www.google.com?

***UPDATE***

I have managed to get it working as follows:

set a route as follows

```
GET  /google    controllers.Default.redirect(to = "http://google.com")
```

and in the controller I change the redirect to:

```
Redirect("google", 302)
```

I'm not sure what the pros and cons are of this solution. How is redirect to external URLs supposed to work in Play? Also this doesn't work for me as I don't want to code in the endpoints. For my use case, the redirect url is dynamic. It can be whatever the user supplies to my service.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962694/how-to-redirect-to-external-url-in-play-framework-2-0-java

Comment: That is Java not Scala - it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me in Scala:

```
package controllers

import play.api.mvc.{Action, Controller}

object essai extends Controller{
  def toGoogle() = Action {
    Redirect("http://google.com", 302)
  }

}
```

Comment: where is that method defined? which API?

Comment: This is Java!! I've said already that my application is a Scala one.

Comment: what have you defined in your routes file?

Comment: OK that works for me. So what is the difference between putting "www.google.com" and `http://google.com` in the Redirect method?

Comment: GET     /v1/google                        controllers.essai.toGoogle()

Comment: It looks like you do not need to put that in your routes file. Can you take it out and see if your redirect works please

Comment: I think you need to link your function with a route. How can you access the function without a route ? Can you give more information ?

Comment: No you're right. I was getting mixed up with what I did before, ie having an explicit endpoint for the redirect (see my updated post above). Thanks for your help but I still don't know why Play treats `www.google.com` and `http://google.com` differently

Comment: I think it needs to find the **http://** prefix before treat an Url like external